# Boom Mic Operator Insurance

Tags: insurance, boom, microphone

i have a quick question. if you are working as a freelance boom mic operator recording dialogue for production companies or even just student film makers, do you need any special kind of insurance such as liability insurance in case you injure someone or insurance to protect your equipment?

Comment: this depends on the country where you are operating in. add this to your question and you'll get a clear answer i think

Answer (score 1):

You can always buy your own insurance for liability and/or equipment, but most production companies have their own insurance that will cover you.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to student films, most universities should also have their own liability policies that cover injury;, equipment might be a bit more of a grey area.

Answer (score 0):

If you're based in the UK, BECTU members are granted public liability insurance as part of their membership http://www.bectu.org.uk/get-involved/join-bectu